# My code gives different results on different compilers

Tags: c++

My code gives different results on different compilers, the following code gives 499999998352516354 when I enter 1,1000000000 as my input on vs code which is the desired results while it gives 499999998352516352 on codeforces

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>  
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   cout<<fixed<<setprecision(90);
   long long x,y;
   long long sum=0;
   long long z=1;
   cin>>x;
   for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
   {
      cin>>y;
      sum=y*(y+1)/2;
       z= log2(y);
       sum-=2*(pow(2,1+z)-1);
       cout<<sum<<"\n";
       sum=0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `pow()` on integers. pow() is a floating point function and it can give a result that is 1 less than the expected value because of truncation that happens when converting a floating point number to int.

Comment: I tried float m=z;       
       sum-=2*(pow(2,1+m)-1); but I got the same results

Comment: Don't use `pow` on integers, especially powers of 2. For powers of 2 use the `<<` operator. Instead of `pow(2, n)` use `(1 << n)`.

Comment: and never use the `using` above. See [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/995714), [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use [std::llround()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) function around `pow()` and your code will work.

It is because pow() gives floating value which can be incorrectly truncated to 1 less than needed. And llround() gives correct rounding to whole integer.

Below is fixed code, I also adjusted code formatting and changed to correct necessary C++ headers.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/6KGTWK63P)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << fixed << setprecision(90);
    long long x, y;
    long long sum = 0;
    long long z = 1;
    cin >> x;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        cin >> y;
        sum = y * (y + 1) / 2;
        z = log2(y);
        sum -= 2 * (llround(pow(2, 1 + z)) - 1);
        cout << sum << "\n";
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

Input:

```
1 1000000000
```

Output:

```
499999998352516354
```

---

As it is suggested in comments you may also use bit shifting `1LL << x` instead of `pow(2, x)` if `x` is non-negative integer. And instead `log2(y)`
if `y` is integer then one can use `std::bit_width(y) - 1` (read about [std::bit_width](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_width))

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/edzK94n7K)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <bit>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << fixed << setprecision(90);
    long long x, y;
    long long sum = 0;
    long long z = 1;
    cin >> x;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        cin >> y;
        sum = y * (y + 1) / 2;
        z = std::bit_width<unsigned long long>(y) - 1;
        sum -= 2 * ((1LL << (1 + z)) - 1);
        cout << sum << "\n";
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is terrible advice. If you want integer numbers with precision, you use bit shifts and integer operations. Don't encourage approximate floating point answer to integer-precision problems

Comment: `log2` needs consideration too.

Comment: @Bathsheba log2 is correctly truncated, if truncation logic is the correct one. If you change log2 to rounding it will give incorrect answer, not equal to the one OP said. If you want you can do `llround(log2(y) - 0.5)`, but it is same as just casting to integer, which does truncation towards 0.

Comment: @drescherjm Fixed, provided second code snippet that uses shifting.

Comment: @Jeffrey Fixed, added second code snippet that does bit shifting.

Comment: @Arty: There are no guarantees under IEEE754 that `log2` is correctly truncated. One of the problems with early implementations of pow(x, y) is that it can be implemented as exp(y log(x)). Chipsets do a better job with exp than they do with log.

Comment: @Bathsheba Just now added in Part-3 of my answer example of how log2() can be fixed. If it is what you wanted please tell me. If not then please suggest how to correct it better.

Comment: `log2` is a bad way to get integer log2. Use `std::bit_width` instead

Comment: Best way IMHO is to use a library that implements pow for integer arguments (something like exponentation by squaring). `std::bit_width` is a better choice for `log2` for your case.

Comment: @phuclv: We in the same room?

Comment: @phuclv Just updated Part-2 of my answer to use `std::bit_width` as you suggested.

Comment: @Bathsheba Just updated Part-2 of my answer to use `std::bit_width` as you suggested.